# What does "unary minus" mean for Matrices

Tags: matrix, terminology

When we're talking about matrices or a matrix, what does "unary minus" stand for as an arithmetic operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix A with all the elements negated.

That way, A + (-A) == 0.

Edit: here's the source from http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/">JAMA:

```
/**  Unary minus
@return    -A
 */
public Matrix uminus () {
   Matrix X = new Matrix(m,n);
   double[][] C = X.getArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         C[i][j] = -A[i][j];
      }
   }
   return X;
}
```

Edit 2: if A is

```
1 2
3 4
```

then unary minus of A is

```
-1 -2
-3 -4
```

Comment: Let's say we have a matrix such that:

A=
| 1 2 |
| 3 4 |

Is -A =
| -1 -2 |
| -3 -4 |

?

Comment: But (| 1 2 |\n| 3 4 |))+ |-1 -2 |\n|-3 -4 |) is not 0 ? (\n=newline)

Answer (score 1):

If M is your matrix, -M is the new matrix where unary minus has been applied

(-M)[i, j] = - (M [i, j])

Answer (score 1):

"unary minus" for a matrix is an element by element negation as others has said.

More generally, in computer science, a "unary operator" is one that operates on a single operand.  Other common examples from C include the '++' or '=*' unary operators.